# Codeigniter how to add a year to user's signup date

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, date

I have a user signup form, and I need to insert a function to create the clients expiry date. Either 1 year or 2 depending on dropdown choice.

How could I add the year value to the signup date upon user creation?

Here is my controller for a new user

```
    function new_member()
{
    $data = array(
        'Last_Name' => $this->input->post('Last_Name'),
        'First_Name' => $this->input->post('First_Name'),
        'Salutation' => $this->input->post('Salutation'),
        'Address' => $this->input->post('Address'),
        'City' => $this->input->post('City'),
        'Province' => $this->input->post('Province'),
        'Postal' => $this->input->post('Postal'),
        'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
        'Dial_Up' => $this->input->post('Dial_Up'),
        'Phone_1' => $this->input->post('Phone_1'),
        'Phone_2' => $this->input->post('Phone_2'),
        'Language' => $this->input->post('Language'),
        'Membership_Cat' => $this->input->post('Membership_Cat'),
        'Special_Member_Cat' => $this->input->post('Special_Member_Cat'),
        'Membership_Status' => $this->input->post('Membership_Status'),
        'Date_DNR' => $this->input->post('Date_DNR'),
        'Gift_Membership' => $this->input->post('Gift_Membership'),
        'Gift_Giver' => $this->input->post('Gift_Giver'),
        'Membership_Length' => $this->input->post('Membership_Length'),
        'Dues_Paid' => $this->input->post('Dues_Paid'),
        'Donation' => $this->input->post('Donation'),
        'Payment_Method' => $this->input->post('Payment_Method'),
        'Date_Received' => $this->input->post('Date_Received'),
        'Date_Input' => $this->input->post('Date_Input'),
        'Membership_Date' => $this->input->post('Membership_Date'),
        'Renew_Letter_1' => $this->input->post('Renew_Letter_1'),
        'Renew_Letter_2' => $this->input->post('Renew_Letter_2'),
        'Renew_Letter_3' => $this->input->post('Renew_Letter_3'),
        'Date_Letter_Sent' => $this->input->post('Date_Letter_Sent'),
        'Vol_FA' => $this->input->post('Vol_FA'),
        'Vol_TEL' => $this->input->post('Vol_TEL'),
        'Vol_CD' => $this->input->post('Vol_CD'),
        'Vol_SCBA' => $this->input->post('Vol_SCBA'),
        'Vol_MAIL' => $this->input->post('Vol_MAIL'),
        'Vol_SML' => $this->input->post('Vol_SML'),
        'Vol_BODCOM' => $this->input->post('Vol_BODCOM'),
        'Vol_OTHER' => $this->input->post('Vol_OTHER'),
        'Member_Since' => $this->input->post('Member_Since'),
        'Notes' => $this->input->post('Notes'),
        );

    $this->membership_model->add_record($data);
    $this->load->view('index_view');
}
```

This is my model

```
    function add_record($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('Membership', $data);
    return;
}
```

any help is appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took both your suggestions and looked into the strtotime function. Since I have 2 lengths of membership, 1 and 2 years, I needed to also come up with a variable in the function. Just finished testing it, here it is

```
$Membership_Length = $this->input->post('Membership_Length');
        if($Membership_Length == "1")
        {
            $length = "+1 year";
        }
        else
        {
            $length = "+2 years";
        }

    $Expiry_Date1 = $this->input->post('Membership_Date');
    $Expiry_Date = strtotime($length , strtotime($Expiry_Date1));
    $Expiry_Date = date('Y-m-j', $Expiry_Date);
    $date_expiry_array = array('Expiry_Date' => $Expiry_Date);
    $data = array_merge($data, $date_expiry_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PHP strtotime() function e.g

```
$expiry = date('yy-mm-dd', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have setup your data array you can use an option like this:

```
$date_received = $this->input->post('Date_Received');
$date_expiry =   strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_received)). " +1 year";
$date_expiry_array = array('Date_Received'=>$date_expiry);
$data = array_merge($data, $date_expiry_array);
```

or if you used this approach:

```
$date_received = $this->input->post('date_received');
$data['date_received'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_received)). " +1 year
```

";

If you want to test for 1 or 2 year length of expiration you could add an if statement to test the value of date_received and then add the number of years based on that value.